# Importing CSV table into SQL Server with Python pandas

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, csv

This is the largest help request I've ever written. My current process is to try to keep narrowing it down until I get the smallest code that can produce an error.

I have downloaded the attributes_active csv table from https://www.ffiec.gov/npw/FinancialReport/DataDownload .

I'm trying to load that into a table in SQL Server. It won't import directly (it eventually needs to be done automatically, so I need to figure out the python anyway). But it won't import directly.

Interesting note: I can import this file directly into an MS Access database. It produces an error table. If I tell it that the double quote character is used for strings, then it imports with no errors.

So I use it to produce the error table, and it tells me for example that row 53 is a problem (it's actually 54, if you include the header)

The first few lines of the access import errors look like this:

```
Error   Field   Row
Type Conversion Failure ORG_TYPE_CD 53
Type Conversion Failure STATE_CD    53
Type Conversion Failure ID_FDIC_CERT    53
Type Conversion Failure SLHC_TYPE_IND   53
Type Conversion Failure CNTRY_INC_CD    53
Type Conversion Failure ORG_TYPE_CD 56
Type Conversion Failure STATE_CD    56
Type Conversion Failure ID_FDIC_CERT    56
Type Conversion Failure SLHC_TYPE_IND   56
Type Conversion Failure CNTRY_INC_CD    56
Type Conversion Failure ORG_TYPE_CD 523
Type Conversion Failure STATE_CD    523
Type Conversion Failure ID_FDIC_CERT    523
Type Conversion Failure SLHC_TYPE_IND   523
Type Conversion Failure CNTRY_INC_CD    523
Type Conversion Failure ID_FDIC_CERT    610
Type Conversion Failure SLHC_TYPE_IND   610
Type Conversion Failure CNTRY_INC_CD    610
Type Conversion Failure ORG_TYPE_CD 714
Type Conversion Failure STATE_CD    714
Type Conversion Failure ID_FDIC_CERT    714
Type Conversion Failure SLHC_TYPE_IND   714
Type Conversion Failure CNTRY_INC_CD    714
Type Conversion Failure ORG_TYPE_CD 759
Type Conversion Failure STATE_CD    759
Type Conversion Failure ID_FDIC_CERT    759
Type Conversion Failure SLHC_TYPE_IND   759
Type Conversion Failure CNTRY_INC_CD    759
Type Conversion Failure ORG_TYPE_CD 796
Type Conversion Failure STATE_CD    796
Type Conversion Failure ID_FDIC_CERT    796
Type Conversion Failure SLHC_TYPE_IND   796
Type Conversion Failure CNTRY_INC_CD    796
```

The problem is I look at the raw text of those lines and those fields and there's nothing odd to distinguish them from the same fields in the adjacent lines. I do however think the fact that I get no import errors when I specifically tell access to use the double quote for strings is significant - but I'm doing the same thing for the pandas!

I'm using the following code to try to read this into SQL Server:

```
def ingest_npw_attributes_active():
    filename = 'CSV_ATTRIBUTES_ACTIVE.CSV'
    full_filename = os.path.join(raw_data_dir, filename)
    print(full_filename)
    dt = {'AUTH_REG_DIST_FRS': int,
          'STREET_LINE2': "string",
          'ID_THRIFT': "string",
          'ID_TAX': int
          }

    init_connection()
    df = pd.read_csv(full_filename, dtype=dt, header=0, quotechar='"')

    place_holder = "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,"
    place_holder += "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?"
    sql_str = "exec dbo.save_attributes_active " + place_holder

    # build assignment string for sql
    values = "("
    for col_name in df.columns:
        values += "row['" + col_name + "'], "
    values = values[:-1] + ")"

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
      if index < 2:
        print(row)
        values = (row['#ID_RSSD'], row['D_DT_START'], row['D_DT_END'], row['BHC_IND'], row['BROAD_REG_CD'],
                  row['CHTR_AUTH_CD'], row['CHTR_TYPE_CD'], row['FBO_4C9_IND'], row['FHC_IND'], row['FUNC_REG'],
                  row['INSUR_PRI_CD'], row['MBR_FHLBS_IND'], row['MBR_FRS_IND'], row['SEC_RPTG_STATUS'],
                  row['EST_TYPE_CD'], row['BANK_CNT'], row['BNK_TYPE_ANALYS_CD'], row['D_DT_EXIST_CMNC'],
                  row['D_DT_EXIST_TERM'], row['FISC_YREND_MMDD'], row['D_DT_INSUR'], row['D_DT_OPEN'],
                  row['FNCL_SUB_HOLDER'], row['FNCL_SUB_IND'], row['IBA_GRNDFTHR_IND'], row['IBF_IND'],
                  row['ID_RSSD_HD_OFF'], row['MJR_OWN_MNRTY'], row['NM_LGL'], row['NM_SHORT'], row['NM_SRCH_CD'],
                  row['ORG_TYPE_CD'], row['REASON_TERM_CD'], row['CNSRVTR_CD'], row['ENTITY_TYPE'],
                  row['AUTH_REG_DIST_FRS'], row['ACT_PRIM_CD'], row['CITY'], row['CNTRY_NM'], row['ID_CUSIP'],
                  row['STATE_ABBR_NM'], row['PLACE_CD'], row['STATE_CD'], row['STATE_HOME_CD'], row['STREET_LINE1'],
                  row['STREET_LINE2'], row['ZIP_CD'], row['ID_THRIFT'], row['ID_THRIFT_HC'], row['DOMESTIC_IND'],
                  row['ID_ABA_PRIM'], row['ID_FDIC_CERT'], row['ID_NCUA'], row['COUNTY_CD'], row['DIST_FRS'],
                  row['ID_OCC'], row['CNTRY_CD'], row['DT_END'], row['DT_EXIST_CMNC'], row['DT_EXIST_TERM'],
                  row['DT_INSUR'], row['DT_OPEN'], row['DT_START'], row['ID_TAX'], row['PROV_REGION'], row['URL'],
                  row['SLHC_IND'], row['SLHC_TYPE_IND'], row['PRIM_FED_REG'], row['STATE_INC_CD'], row['CNTRY_INC_CD'],
                  row['STATE_INC_ABBR_NM'], row['CNTRY_INC_NM'], row['ID_LEI'], row['IHC_IND'])

    # print(values)
    return_key = cursor.execute(sql_str, values).fetchval()
    print('return_key =', return_key)

    conn.close()
    return
```

I have the SQL Server table defined as follows:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[npwAttributesActive]
(
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID_RSSD] [int] NOT NULL,
    [D_DT_START] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [D_DT_END] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [BHC_IND] [int] NULL,
    [BROAD_REG_CD] [int] NULL,
    [CHTR_AUTH_CD] [int] NULL,
    [CHTR_TYPE_CD] [int] NULL,
    [FBO_4C9_IND] [int] NULL,
    [FHC_IND] [int] NULL,
    [FUNC_REG] [int] NULL,
    [INSUR_PRI_CD] [int] NULL,
    [MBR_FHLBS_IND] [int] NULL,
    [MBR_FRS_IND] [int] NULL,
    [SEC_RPTG_STATUS] [int] NULL,
    [EST_TYPE_CD] [int] NULL,
    [BANK_CNT] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [BNK_TYPE_ANALYS_CD] [int] NULL,
    [D_DT_EXIST_CMNC] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [D_DT_EXIST_TERM] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FISC_YREND_MMDD] [int] NULL,
    [D_DT_INSUR] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [D_DT_OPEN] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FNCL_SUB_HOLDER] [int] NULL,
    [FNCL_SUB_IND] [int] NULL,
    [IBA_GRNDFTHR_IND] [int] NULL,
    [IBF_IND] [int] NULL,
    [ID_RSSD_HD_OFF] [int] NULL,
    [MJR_OWN_MNRTY] [int] NULL,
    [NM_LGL] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [NM_SHORT] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [NM_SRCH_CD] [int] NULL,
    [ORG_TYPE_CD] [int] NULL,
    [REASON_TERM_CD] [int] NULL,
    [CNSRVTR_CD] [int] NULL,
    [ENTITY_TYPE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AUTH_REG_DIST_FRS] [int] NULL,
    [ACT_PRIM_CD] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CITY] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CNTRY_NM] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ID_CUSIP] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [STATE_ABBR_NM] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PLACE_CD] [int] NULL,
    [STATE_CD] [int] NULL,
    [STATE_HOME_CD] [int] NULL,
    [STREET_LINE1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [STREET_LINE2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ZIP_CD] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ID_THRIFT] [int] NULL,
    [ID_THRIFT_HC] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DOMESTIC_IND] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ID_ABA_PRIM] [int] NULL,
    [ID_FDIC_CERT] [int] NULL,
    [ID_NCUA] [int] NULL,
    [COUNTY_CD] [int] NULL,
    [DIST_FRS] [int] NULL,
    [ID_OCC] [int] NULL,
    [CNTRY_CD] [int] NULL,
    [DT_END] [int] NULL,
    [DT_EXIST_CMNC] [int] NULL,
    [DT_EXIST_TERM] [int] NULL,
    [DT_INSUR] [int] NULL,
    [DT_OPEN] [int] NULL,
    [DT_START] [int] NULL,
    [ID_TAX] [int] NULL,
    [PROV_REGION] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [URL] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SLHC_IND] [int] NULL,
    [SLHC_TYPE_IND] [int] NULL,
    [PRIM_FED_REG] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [STATE_INC_CD] [int] NULL,
    [CNTRY_INC_CD] [int] NULL,
    [STATE_INC_ABBR_NM] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CNTRY_INC_NM] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ID_LEI] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IHC_IND] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The stored procedure is

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[save_attributes_active]
    @ID_RSSD       int,
    @D_DT_START    nvarchar(50),
    @D_DT_END      nvarchar(50),
    @BHC_IND       int,
    @BROAD_REG_CD  int,
    @CHTR_AUTH_CD  int,
    @CHTR_TYPE_CD  int,
    @FBO_4C9_IND   int,
    @FHC_IND       int,
    @FUNC_REG      int,
    @INSUR_PRI_CD  int,
    @MBR_FHLBS_IND      int,
    @MBR_FRS_IND        int,
    @SEC_RPTG_STATUS    int,
    @EST_TYPE_CD        int,
    @BANK_CNT           nvarchar(1),
    @BNK_TYPE_ANALYS_CD int,
    @D_DT_EXIST_CMNC    nvarchar(50),
    @D_DT_EXIST_TERM    nvarchar(50),
    @FISC_YREND_MMDD    int,
    @D_DT_INSUR         nvarchar(50),
    @D_DT_OPEN          nvarchar(50),
    @FNCL_SUB_HOLDER    int,
    @FNCL_SUB_IND       int,
    @IBA_GRNDFTHR_IND   int,
    @IBF_IND            int,
    @ID_RSSD_HD_OFF     int,
    @MJR_OWN_MNRTY      int,
    @NM_LGL             nvarchar(150),
    @NM_SHORT           nvarchar(50),
    @NM_SRCH_CD         int,
    @ORG_TYPE_CD        int,
    @REASON_TERM_CD     int,
    @CNSRVTR_CD         int,
    @ENTITY_TYPE        nvarchar(50),
    @AUTH_REG_DIST_FRS  int,
    @ACT_PRIM_CD        nvarchar(50),
    @CITY               nvarchar(50),
    @CNTRY_NM           nvarchar(50),
    @ID_CUSIP           nvarchar(50),
    @STATE_ABBR_NM      nvarchar(50),
    @PLACE_CD           int,
    @STATE_CD           int,
    @STATE_HOME_CD      int,
    @STREET_LINE1       nvarchar(50),
    @STREET_LINE2       nvarchar(50),
    @ZIP_CD             nvarchar(50),
    @ID_THRIFT          int,
    @ID_THRIFT_HC       nvarchar(50),
    @DOMESTIC_IND       nvarchar(50),
    @ID_ABA_PRIM        int,
    @ID_FDIC_CERT       int,
    @ID_NCUA            int,
    @COUNTY_CD          int,
    @DIST_FRS           int,
    @ID_OCC             int,
    @CNTRY_CD           int,
    @DT_END             int,
    @DT_EXIST_CMNC      int,
    @DT_EXIST_TERM      int,
    @DT_INSUR           int,
    @DT_OPEN            int,
    @DT_START           int,
    @ID_TAX             int,
    @PROV_REGION        nvarchar(50),
    @URL                nvarchar(50),
    @SLHC_IND           int,
    @SLHC_TYPE_IND      int,
    @PRIM_FED_REG       nvarchar(50),
    @STATE_INC_CD       int,
    @CNTRY_INC_CD       int,
    @STATE_INC_ABBR_NM  nvarchar(50),
    @CNTRY_INC_NM       nvarchar(50),
    @ID_LEI             nvarchar(50),
    @IHC_IND            int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.npwAttributesActive ([ID_RSSD], [D_DT_START], [D_DT_END], [BHC_IND], [BROAD_REG_CD], [CHTR_AUTH_CD], [CHTR_TYPE_CD], [FBO_4C9_IND], [FHC_IND], [FUNC_REG], [INSUR_PRI_CD],
         [MBR_FHLBS_IND], [MBR_FRS_IND], [SEC_RPTG_STATUS], [EST_TYPE_CD], [BANK_CNT], [BNK_TYPE_ANALYS_CD], [D_DT_EXIST_CMNC], [D_DT_EXIST_TERM], [FISC_YREND_MMDD], [D_DT_INSUR], [D_DT_OPEN], 
         [FNCL_SUB_HOLDER], [FNCL_SUB_IND], [IBA_GRNDFTHR_IND], [IBF_IND], [ID_RSSD_HD_OFF], [MJR_OWN_MNRTY], [NM_LGL], [NM_SHORT], [NM_SRCH_CD], [ORG_TYPE_CD], [REASON_TERM_CD], [CNSRVTR_CD], 
         [ENTITY_TYPE], [AUTH_REG_DIST_FRS], [ACT_PRIM_CD], [CITY], [CNTRY_NM], [ID_CUSIP], [STATE_ABBR_NM], [PLACE_CD], [STATE_CD], [STATE_HOME_CD], [STREET_LINE1], [STREET_LINE2], [ZIP_CD], 
         [ID_THRIFT], [ID_THRIFT_HC], [DOMESTIC_IND], [ID_ABA_PRIM], [ID_FDIC_CERT], [ID_NCUA], [COUNTY_CD], [DIST_FRS], [ID_OCC], [CNTRY_CD], [DT_END], [DT_EXIST_CMNC], [DT_EXIST_TERM], [DT_INSUR],
         [DT_OPEN], [DT_START], [ID_TAX], [PROV_REGION], [URL], [SLHC_IND], [SLHC_TYPE_IND], [PRIM_FED_REG], [STATE_INC_CD], [CNTRY_INC_CD],
         [STATE_INC_ABBR_NM], [CNTRY_INC_NM], [ID_LEI], [IHC_IND] ) 
    VALUES (@ID_RSSD, @D_DT_START, @D_DT_END, @BHC_IND, @BROAD_REG_CD, @CHTR_AUTH_CD, @CHTR_TYPE_CD, @FBO_4C9_IND, @FHC_IND, @FUNC_REG, @INSUR_PRI_CD,
        @MBR_FHLBS_IND, @MBR_FRS_IND, @SEC_RPTG_STATUS, @EST_TYPE_CD, @BANK_CNT, @BNK_TYPE_ANALYS_CD, @D_DT_EXIST_CMNC, @D_DT_EXIST_TERM, @FISC_YREND_MMDD,
        @D_DT_INSUR, @D_DT_OPEN, @FNCL_SUB_HOLDER, @FNCL_SUB_IND, @IBA_GRNDFTHR_IND, @IBF_IND, @ID_RSSD_HD_OFF, @MJR_OWN_MNRTY, @NM_LGL, @NM_SHORT, @NM_SRCH_CD, 
        @ORG_TYPE_CD, @REASON_TERM_CD, @CNSRVTR_CD, @ENTITY_TYPE, @AUTH_REG_DIST_FRS, @ACT_PRIM_CD, @CITY, @CNTRY_NM, @ID_CUSIP, @STATE_ABBR_NM, @PLACE_CD, @STATE_CD,
        @STATE_HOME_CD, @STREET_LINE1, @STREET_LINE2, @ZIP_CD, @ID_THRIFT, @ID_THRIFT_HC, @DOMESTIC_IND, @ID_ABA_PRIM, @ID_FDIC_CERT, @ID_NCUA, @COUNTY_CD, @DIST_FRS,
        @ID_OCC, @CNTRY_CD, @DT_END, @DT_EXIST_CMNC, @DT_EXIST_TERM, @DT_INSUR, @DT_OPEN, @DT_START, @ID_TAX, @PROV_REGION, @URL, @SLHC_IND, @SLHC_TYPE_IND,
        @PRIM_FED_REG, @STATE_INC_CD, @CNTRY_INC_CD, @STATE_INC_ABBR_NM, @CNTRY_INC_NM, @ID_LEI, @IHC_IND
    )

    SELECT 1
END
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kgreen/Source/Repos/MapTools/ingest_source.py", line 142, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/kgreen/Source/Repos/MapTools/ingest_source.py", line 136, in main
    ingest_npw_data()
  File "C:/Users/kgreen/Source/Repos/MapTools/ingest_source.py", line 130, in ingest_npw_data
    ingest_npw_attributes_active()
  File "C:/Users/kgreen/Source/Repos/MapTools/ingest_source.py", line 122, in ingest_npw_attributes_active
    return_key = cursor.execute(sql_str, values).fetchval()
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 19 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision. (8023) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Addendum
First few lines of the CSV

```
#ID_RSSD,D_DT_START,D_DT_END,BHC_IND,BROAD_REG_CD,CHTR_AUTH_CD,CHTR_TYPE_CD,FBO_4C9_IND,FHC_IND,FUNC_REG,INSUR_PRI_CD,MBR_FHLBS_IND,MBR_FRS_IND,SEC_RPTG_STATUS,EST_TYPE_CD,BANK_CNT,BNK_TYPE_ANALYS_CD,D_DT_EXIST_CMNC,D_DT_EXIST_TERM,FISC_YREND_MMDD,D_DT_INSUR,D_DT_OPEN,FNCL_SUB_HOLDER,FNCL_SUB_IND,IBA_GRNDFTHR_IND,IBF_IND,ID_RSSD_HD_OFF,MJR_OWN_MNRTY,NM_LGL,NM_SHORT,NM_SRCH_CD,ORG_TYPE_CD,REASON_TERM_CD,CNSRVTR_CD,ENTITY_TYPE,AUTH_REG_DIST_FRS,ACT_PRIM_CD,CITY,CNTRY_NM,ID_CUSIP,STATE_ABBR_NM,PLACE_CD,STATE_CD,STATE_HOME_CD,STREET_LINE1,STREET_LINE2,ZIP_CD,ID_THRIFT,ID_THRIFT_HC,DOMESTIC_IND,ID_ABA_PRIM,ID_FDIC_CERT,ID_NCUA,COUNTY_CD,DIST_FRS,ID_OCC,CNTRY_CD,DT_END,DT_EXIST_CMNC,DT_EXIST_TERM,DT_INSUR,DT_OPEN,DT_START,ID_TAX,PROV_REGION,URL,SLHC_IND,SLHC_TYPE_IND,PRIM_FED_REG,STATE_INC_CD,CNTRY_INC_CD,STATE_INC_ABBR_NM,CNTRY_INC_NM,ID_LEI,IHC_IND
37,"04/15/2009 00:00:00","12/31/9999 00:00:00",0,1,2,200,0,0,0,7,1,0,0,1,,0,,"12/31/9999 00:00:00",0,"01/01/1934 00:00:00","09/01/1904 00:00:00",0,0,0,0,0,0,"BANK OF HANCOCK COUNTY                                                                                                  ","BANK OF HANCOCK CTY           ",1072861144,1,0,0,"NMB",6,"52211 ","SPARTA","UNITED STATES                           ","0","GA",72584,13,0,"12855 BROAD STREET","0","31087    ",16553,"0","Y",61107146,10057,0,141,6,0,1007,99991231,0,99991231,19340101,19040901,20090415,0,"0","0",0,0,"FDIC",0,0,"0 ","","0",0
73,"12/31/2008 00:00:00","12/31/9999 00:00:00",0,2,1,330,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,,0,,"12/31/9999 00:00:00",0,"01/04/1971 00:00:00","01/01/1936 00:00:00",0,0,0,0,0,0,"UTILITY EMPLOYEES FEDERAL CREDIT UNION                                                                                  ","UTILITY EMPL FCU              ",788018087,6,0,0,"FCU",12,"52213 ","HOQUIAM","UNITED STATES                           ","0","WA",0,53,0,"220 MYRTLE STREET","0","98550    ",0,"0","Y",325179988,0,1851,27,12,0,1007,99991231,0,99991231,19710104,19360101,20081231,910591861,"0","0",0,0,"NCUA",0,0,"0 ","","0",0
242,"01/01/2012 00:00:00","12/31/9999 00:00:00",0,1,2,200,0,0,0,7,1,1,0,1,,0,,"12/31/9999 00:00:00",0,"01/01/1934 00:00:00","01/01/1922 00:00:00",0,0,0,0,0,0,"FIRST COMMUNITY BANK XENIA-FLORA                                                                                        ","FIRST CMNTY BK XENIA FLORA    ",574907456,1,0,0,"SMB",8,"52211 ","XENIA","UNITED STATES                           ","0","IL",83739,17,0,"260 FRONT STREET","0","62899    ",0,"0","Y",81220537,3850,0,25,8,0,1007,99991231,0,99991231,19340101,19220101,20120101,370274860,"0","WWW.FCBXENIAFLORA.COM/INDEX.HTML",0,0,"FRS",17,0,"IL","","0",0
279,"01/01/2012 00:00:00","12/31/9999 00:00:00",0,1,2,300,0,0,0,7,1,0,0,1,,0,,"12/31/9999 00:00:00",0,"01/01/1997 00:00:00","01/01/1934 00:00:00",0,0,0,0,0,0,"MINEOLA COMMUNITY BANK, SSB                                                                                             ","MINEOLA CMNTY BK SSB          ",98889854,6,0,0,"SSB",11,"52211 ","MINEOLA","UNITED STATES                           ","0","TX",48648,48,0,"215 W BROAD","0","75773    ",2523,"0","Y",311972526,28868,0,499,11,0,1007,99991231,0,99991231,19970101,19340101,20120101,750440734,"0","0",0,0,"FDIC",48,0,"TX","","0",0
354,"12/04/2019 00:00:00","12/31/9999 00:00:00",0,1,2,200,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,1,,0,"01/01/1901 00:00:00","12/31/9999 00:00:00",0,"03/21/1934 00:00:00","01/01/1901 00:00:00",0,0,0,0,0,0,"BISON STATE BANK                                                                                                        ","BISON ST BK                   ",715161421,1,0,0,"NMB",10,"52211 ","BISON","UNITED STATES                           ","0","KS",6950,20,0,"223 MAIN STREET","0","67520    ",0,"0","Y",101107475,14083,0,165,10,0,1007,99991231,19010101,99991231,19340321,19010101,20191204,0,"0","0",0,0,"FDIC",0,0,"0 ","","0",0
```

Comment: @Parfait I added the CSVsample  to the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Without actually seeing full set of CSV data, your issue may essentially come down to blanks showing up in CSV cells.

**CSV -> MS Access Type Conversion**

Without a specified table, MS Access imports data based on reading first few rows. Before specifying double quotes, Access reads `""` as zero-empty string which will be problematic if Access initially defined corresponding fields as `int`, `double`, or `date/time`.

**Pandas -> SQL Server Type Conversion**

Similarly, Pandas reads data based on first few rows if not specified as you did with `dtype` argument. Empty strings may be the issue when migrating the Pandas data frame to SQL Server table. Per your error, you may have CSV cells with `""` and attempting to migrate to non-string columns:

> Parameter 19 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float.

By default, `read_csv` will convert values with `""` in integer columns to `NaN` and thereby rendering entire column to `float`, no longer `int` which can impact migration. There may no specific solution for you but consider an array of solutions that may need to be combined:

- Use the `na_filter` option in `read_csv` that does not replace blanks with `NaN` but does convert number columns with empty strings as `object` which may affect SQL Server import.

  ```
  df = pd.read_csv(full_filename, dtype=dt, na_filter=False)
  ```

  Note `quote='"'` is already the default and `header=0` may be redundant if not replacing `names`.
- Read as normal, then convert all columns to object and replace blanks with `None` which translates properly to `NULL` in SQL. Possibly, `pyodbc` will attempt to cast to final types.

  ```
  df = pd.read_csv(full_filename, dtype=dt)

  df = df.astype(object).where(pd.notnull(df), None)
  ```

  Alternatively, dump to a staging temp table of all `varchar` and run `UPDATE` or `MERGE` with type casting to final table. This can all be handled in stored procedure.
- Individually adjust each number column to anticipate empty blanks. Maybe place a placeholder value `9999` in blank integers to be cleaned out after migration.

  ```
  df['D_DT_EXIST_TERM'] = df['D_DT_EXIST_TERM'].replace('', None)

  df['FISC_YREND_MMDD'] = df['FISC_YREND_MMDD'].fillna(9999).astype('int')
  ```

Finally, maybe you can avoid using the heavy library, `pandas`, altogether which is best for data analytics, and migrate with built-in `csv` module using `csv.reader`. This may better handle blanks cast as `None` (and not Numpy's `np.nan` float entity) . Many online blogs, tutorials, and questions can help with this approach. To better control CSV column to SQL column alignment, look into `csv.DictReader`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from getpass import getpass
from mysql.connector import connect, Error
import pandas as pd

def query_execute(cmd):
    print(f"{cmd}")
    try:
        query.execute(cmd)
        for i in query:
            print(i)
    except Error as e:
        print(f"{e}\n\n")

def dblq(ar):
    b = '\"'
    e = '\",'
    dbl = ""
    for i in ar[:-1]:
        if isinstance(i, str):
            dbl += f"{b}{i}{e}"
        else:
            dbl += f"{i},"
    if isinstance(ar[-1], str):
        dbl += f"{b}{ar[-1]}{b}"
    else:
        dbl += f"{ar[-1]}"
    return (dbl)

def noqs(ar):
    noq = ""
    for i in ar[:-1]:
        noq += f"{i}, "
    noq += f"{ar[-1]}"
    return (noq)


mydb = connect(
    host="localhost",
    user=input("Enter username: "),
    password=getpass("Enter Password: "),
    database="entropia"
)
query = mydb.cursor()

# Dictionary map data type pandas to sql
map_types = {'object': 'VARCHAR', 'int64': 'INT', 'float64': 'FLOAT'}

df = pd.read_csv('./Data/EU-Assets.csv')
info_ar = []
dfd = df.dtypes
for c, i in enumerate(list(df.columns.values)):
    info_ar.append([i, max(df[i].astype(str).map(len)), str(dfd[c])])

names = tuple(df.columns.values)
Values = [f"{i} {map_types[info_ar[c][2]]}({info_ar[c][1]})" for c, i in enumerate(names)]
make_table = ["CREATE TABLE assetz ("]
for i in Values[:-1]:
    make_table.append(f"{i},")
make_table.append(f"{Values[-1]})")

create_table = str(tuple(make_table)).replace("'", "").replace(",,", ",").replace("(,", "(").replace(")))", "))")
query_execute(f"{create_table[1:]}")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index < len(df):
        query_execute(f"INSERT INTO assetz ({noqs(names)}) VALUES ({dblq(tuple(row))})")
mydb.commit()
```